# Linear regression between two raster images in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, raster, r-raster

I need a linear regression for calculating an empirical parameter. L1 is a raster image, format .tif. L2 is a raster image as well, calculated beforehand. Both images have the same number of columns and rows.

The formula is:
L1 = *a* + *b* * L2 which translates in R as:

```
lm(L1 ~ L2)
```

In a second formula I later need *a* nd *b*.

I am now facing the problem, that both raster contain NA values and I not sure how to build the function for the linear regression.
I am not that familiar with R so I am stuck at this problem which might be rather simple. I think I have to use calc, but not sure how.

**Edit**: So far I have this code:

```
s = stack(L1,L2)
fun = function(x) {if (is.na(x[1])) { NA } else {lm(x[1] ~ x[2])$coefficients[2]}}
```

However, it takes a really long time calculating and does not come to an result

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You would use `calc` if you wanted to do *local* regression, that is a separate regression for each grid cell (pixel). But that makes no sense in this case as you only have two rasters; and thus only one data point per grid cell.

In your case, you appear to want a *global* regression. You can that like this:

```
s <- stack(L1, L2)
v <- data.frame(na.omit(values(s)))
# this step may not be necessary
names(v) <- c('L1', 'L2')
m <- lm(L2 ~ L1, data=v)
m
```

if `s` is too large for that, you can do something like

```
v <- sampleRegular(s, 100000)  
v <- data.frame(na.omit(v))
```

etc.

Now with some data (and showing how to get residuals)

```
library(raster)
f <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")) 
s <- stack(f)
names(s)
v <- data.frame(na.omit(values(s)))
m <- lm(red ~ green, data=v)
m

p <- predict(s, m)
residuals <- s$red - p
```

Comment: Thank you! How would I add a condition, let's say: L2 > 0.0? using which rises an aerror, that the argument is not logical

Comment: you can subset `v`. E.g. `v <- v[v$L2 > 0.0, ]`

Comment: How do you plot the residuals from this model as a new raster layer?

Comment: That would be a new question, but I have added it above